# Accessing globals within a scripted class in CSharpScript

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn

I'm trying to integrate C# scripting into my application. I'm using the *globals* object to make various data available to my scripts.

```
public class Globals
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

However it seems that the *globals* are accessible only on the "global" level of the script. This works:

```
Console.WriteLine(CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>(
    "X + Y",
    globals: new Globals { X = 1, Y = 2 }).Result);
```

When I try to access the *globals* within a scripted class I always end up with an exception:

```
Console.WriteLine(CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>(
    @"class Foo
    {
        public int Bar()
        {
            return X + Y;
        }
    }

    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.Bar()", globals: new Globals { X = 1, Y = 2 }).Result);
```

> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException: (5,24): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Globals.Y'

Are the *globals* expected to only work on the "global" level of the script? From the exception message it seems that the engine correctly identified the `Y` property belonging to the `Globals` object.

I'm using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting v1.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This behavior is by design](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7758):

> Global variables are only accessible in top-level statements and methods, not in classes.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use RunAsync, not EvaluateAsync, and evaluate the variables array in ScriptState.

```
Task<ScriptState<object>> scrstate=CSharpScript.RunAsync(yourscript);
var ret_global = scrstate.Result.Variables[0].Value;
```

Globals will be 0,1,2...

[RunAsync samples](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.UnitTests/ScriptTests.cs)

Comment: I don't have problem with accessing globals after the script finishes. I have problem with accessing globals within the script itself. The script can be run neither through RunAsync nor EvaluateAsync because of the exception mentioned above.